# Requests Module not found in python, after deploying to Azure function

Tags: python, python-requests, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, python-module

Is there any reason why things work all fine in Consumption plan and won't work at all in Premium plan ?

This has me mad, code below, in consumption plan works as expected

_*************

*Import requests*

*Blah blah blah blah I do with requests*

_*************

Same thing breaks when deployed in premium plan, and says Requests module not found

Why God ?

I tried checking requirements.txt & versions, SDK and everything, only thing differing is plan.

Why this shouldn't frustrate when big organization like microsoft does this to their loyal customer base ? With huge following

Please help

Comment: Please don't be dramatic.  Is `requests` in your `requirements.txt`?  Are you sure that it's in the right location?

Comment: What I meant is, are you sure `requirements.txt` is in the right location?  That's a key file for Azure, but it has to be in the right place.

Comment: Even today. After deploying. Azure function isn't still reflecting the new code. I don't understand why new code doesn't take effect sometimes. No product can be 100% and so what happens ? We go mad finding the reason. And sometimes we might not find anything at all. Because no company will admit it's failures and every failures, only some are acknowledged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code:

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import requests


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    return func.HttpResponse(
            "This is a test.",
            status_code=200
    )
```

And this is the requirements.txt on my side:

```
# DO NOT include azure-functions-worker in this file
# The Python Worker is managed by Azure Functions platform
# Manually managing azure-functions-worker may cause unexpected issues

azure-functions
requests
```

This is the structure of my function app:

[image]

The function app on azure is based on premium plan:

[image]

And it works fine on my side:

[image]

Please check the differences between you and me. Or maybe the problem on your side is temporary.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details with image. Thing is even if I don't mention Requests in requirement.txt  in consumption plan, it works fine. And it doesn't work the same way in premium plan. Requests has to be mentioned in requirement.txt. doesn't this open up lot of confusion.

Comment: @santhoshkumarB So you can execute successfully now, right? I suggest you mention the public module in that file regardless of which plan, because when the function host is initialized, the function host relies on it to install Python modules

Comment: Great. That helps. Thanks much dear